# PowerPC Instruction "Mulli" Confusion

Tags: assembly, powerpc

Thanks in advance.

I am a little confused about such a simple task I was looking through the IBM Documentation to find the instruction "Mulli" which I thought would be just a simple multiplication however it turns out not, I get an example of:

```
# Assume GPR 4 holds 0x0000 3000.
mulli 6,4,10
# GPR 6 now holds 0x0001 E000
```

Now if you ask me 
0x00003000 * 10 = 0x30000

I don't understand where the value of 0x0001E000 comes from in the example if anyone could explain this to me that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate value ("`10`") in your instruction:

```
mulli 6,4,10
```

is in decimal, not hex. So you're multipling by (decimal) `10`, or (hex) `0xa`.

```
0x3000 * 10 == 0x3000 * 0xa == 0x1E000
```

Comment: I'm done, I suppose with a programmer brain you always expect hex, cheers anyway.